# What type should std::remove_cv produce on an array of const T?

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits, libstdc++

What type should `std::remove_cv<const int[3]>` produce? `int[3]` or `const int[3]`?

`const int[3]` is an `array of 3 const int` right?, and has no top-level cv-qualifier.  So shouldn't it produce `const int[3]`?  Latest version of gcc/libstdc++ is producing `int[3]` I think.  Is this a bug?  Why / why not?

Comment: While the behavior is sensible, I wonder how it's justified... (One could read it as a `const` array of 3 `int`.)

Comment: Effectively, it will end up using a specialization like `template <typename T> struct remove_cv<T const> { using type = T; };`. I don't think `T const[N]` would match that specialization.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Standard says "The [result type] shall be the same as T except that any top-level cv-qualifier has been removed."

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1059

Answer (score 8, accepted):

N4140 §3.9.3 [basic.type.qualifier]/p5, emphasis mine:

> Cv-qualifiers applied to an array type attach to the underlying
>   element type, so the notation “`cv T`,” where `T` is an array type,
>   refers to an array whose elements are so-qualified. **An array type
>   whose elements are cv-qualified is also considered to have the same
>   cv-qualifications as its elements.** [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> typedef char CA[5];
> typedef const char CC;
> CC arr1[5] = { 0 };
> const CA arr2 = { 0 };
> ```
>
> The type of both `arr1` and `arr2` is “array of 5 `const char`,” and
>   the array type is considered to be `const`-qualified. —*end example* ]

See also [CWG issue 1059](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1059).